# In Java, how to insert multiple OS commands line?

Tags: java, windows, cmd, operating-system, command

I used the following code to execute simple OS command on Windows:

```
public class Ping {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String command = "ping google.com";

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));


        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }


        reader.close();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Finished");
```

How to modify the code to insert multiple commands instead of one, so let us say I want to ping google.com, and then ping yahoo.com after that. 
I tried to create array string like:

```
String [] command = {"ping google.com", "ping yahoo.com"};
```

However, this showed me an error.

I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Then you need to iterate over command, that you in that case can call commands. But what are you trying to achieve with you program? Why not just do this in the terminal or in a bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
String [] commands = {"ping google.com", "ping yahoo.com"};
for(String command: commands) {
     Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
     //more stuff
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you @Gtomika
Could you please explain to me what is the meaning of the condition "String command: commands"

Comment: Called a for-each loop. goes throgh all elements in the array. Its a short way if writing a loop that iterates all elements of a collection.